# Cool summer long drinks

Tags: pairing, drink

It's no secret - I like food.  So, with my somewhat eclectic taste and adventurous spirit I have today decided to cook - Mexican Achiote (annatto) Chicken.  Here's the [recipe](https://food52.com/recipes/56119-mexican-achiote-roast-chicken) and the photo is of the spice itself.  But keeping in mind the color of the spice in its original format, and that the meal is Mexican, what would be a great drink to serve with it?  (I have noted in the heading - long summer drinks, as it's hot here at the moment.)  Any suggestion would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: It's no secret - I like food too. Hope you get some awesome suggestions!

Comment: I tend to find that those who seriously like their food - tend to like to pair it with something 'drinkable'.  Cheers

Comment: @Ken Graham Thanks for the tag edit - I was struggling with them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would go with what I call a **"Bloody Juanita":** Tequila with Sangrita (tomato based).

For Mexican food, Tequila (or Mescal) is the obvious choice. You could go the US way and make some margaritas, but to me that sounds boring (and ideally needs a margarita machine, or at least decent amounts of ice, which is not always available, if you are on a boat or something).

Sangrita is said to be a common partner to Tequila. According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sangrita),:

> Sangrita (meaning "little blood"), whose origin dates back to the 1920s, is a customary partner to a shot of straight tequila blanco; a non-alcoholic accompaniment that highlights tequila's crisp acidity and cleanses the palate between each peppery sip. The basic conception of sangrita is to complement the flavor of 100% agave tequila, which is also peppery and citrusy in taste.

Although originally it's a fruity juice, I would recommend the tomato-based variant as food companion.

> While most outsiders would reference its red make up as tomato juice and spices, locals and traditionalists agree that the one ingredient that most likely doesn't belong is tomato.

Another thing to consider is the Tequila variant to use. Originally clear/silver is the way to go, but I prefer a brown/golden Tequila (can be a fake one, does not have a pricey barrel-aged one).

Mix Sangrita (store-bought or homemade, see linked Wikipedia article for recipes) and Tequila to taste and garnish with a big stem of cilantro, and there you go.

Comment: I like the 'boat or something'!  When I last looked, it was still a boat (and American as well!) and not a 'something', those are the French built boats (no offense intended to the French - just your boat builders!).  I also really like the cilantro garnish idea - I feel a hang over coming on already (again!).

Comment: Your reasoning is bang on.